# How do I prevent the browser from escaping my anchor tags

Tags: html

When I try to pass `select` tag with `anchor` tags wrapped in the `option` tags, the browser removes the anchor tags. Bard tells me that it is removed by an `escape()` function in the browser. How can I prevent this from happening.

I pass this:

```
<select>
  <option><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></option>
  <option><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></option>
</select>
```

And the browser removes the anchor tags and uses this:

```
<select>
  <option>Page 1</option>
  <option>Page 2</option>
</select>
```

Some people say that it is not good practice to do what I am trying to do. But I don't mind.

Please can somebody help me here?

Comment: You can't click links in `option` tags. The browser removes them automatically because you wouldn't be able to use them anyway.

Comment: Why do you want a `<select>` drop down list with entries that have links? What are you trying to do? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You should stop asking Bard or ChatGPT technical questions. It produces responses based on the statistical probability that a string of words goes together. It has no intelligence, and no ability to actually understand or verify the stuff it spits out.

Comment: @user229044 - +1  spitting out truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bard tells me that it is removed by an escape() function in the browser. How can I prevent this from happening.

Bard is telling you utter nonsense. There is no such function for you to suppress.

Option tags simply cannot contain anchor tags. It's invalid markup.

> Some people say that it is not good practice ...  But I don't mind.

You need to mind, because it's not possible. The browser is doing its best to recover from invalid markup by stripping away the invalid part.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, which is wrapping anchor tags  inside  tags within a  element, is not valid HTML and goes against standard web development practices. The behavior you're encountering, where the browser removes the anchor tags, is expected because the content inside  tags should be text only.